# Angular Overlay CDK not attaching to origin

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, overlay

I am trying to create a `simple overlay` panel which appears when I click a button. The button is placed on the top right of the screen and is set as the origin of the overlay. However, the overlay appears on the top left of the screen.

I want the `overlay` to appear right next to the button as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqCJN.png).

The button I am pressing is the profile button to the very right of the `navbar` and the overlay appears on the top left.

```
<div class="flex md:justify-between sm:justify-start">
<app-logo class="m-2 pt-2"></app-logo>
<app-search class="m-2 pt-2"></app-search>
<app-usermenu (click)="toggleMenu()" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin" class="m-2 pt-2"
</app-usermenu>
</div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<ng-template [cdkConnectedOverlay] [cdkOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="toggle">
<mat-card class="menu-card bg-slate-200">
<ul>Account</ul>
<ul>Logout</ul>
</mat-card>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Overlay looks good. What you have in your `toggleMenu` method?

Comment: @wnvko it just does `toggle = !toggle`.